# как вставить серверный код c# в определение javascript события?

Tags: javascript, c#

Есть ли какой-то способ (синтаксис) организовать такой вызов метода SetInputText события onblur ?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFirstName" onfocus="$.ClearInput(this);" onblur='$.SetInputText(this, "<%=regFirstName%>");' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Через разметку нельзя так сделать, только в code-behind'е. Поэтому в разметке уберите `onblur` и создайте обработчик для `Init`'а контрола:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFirstName" onfocus="$.ClearInput(this);" OnInit="tbFirstName_Init" />
```

А в коде:

```
protected void tbFirstName_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ((TextBox)sender).Attributes["onblur"] = string.Format("$.SetInputText(this, '{0}')", regFirstName);
}
```

Или, если можно C# 6, то:

```
protected void tbFirstName_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ((TextBox)sender).Attributes["onblur"] = $"$.SetInputText(this, '{regFirstName}')";
}
```

Comment: Класс, я про behind и не подумал, спасибо!